# CSP style-src-directive with Vue/Vite

Tags: vue.js, vite, content-security-policy

I'm trying to implement a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) for a webapp that uses Vue + Vite for it's frontend. As far as I understand the javascript-code Vue/Vite produces is generally compliant with most forms of CSP, even though it's difficult to find any explicit information on this.

Now, here is the particular issue I stumbled upon:

Part of the CSP-Policy I'm using is `style-src 'self'`. Even though this would normally block [inline-styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src#violation_cases) it doesn't seem to block styles that are set with the vue-style-binding like so:

```
<div :style="{ 'font-size': fontSize + 'px' }"></div>
```

nor does it seem to block inline-styles that are placed in a .vue single-file-component like so:

```
<template>
<div style="background: red">
</template>
```

Even though I don't mind the first one, as this means I don't have to set `'unsafe-inline'` for style-src, I'm kind of wondering why the second example won't be blocked by a `style-src 'self'`  (or even `style-src 'none'`). Is this behavior generally intended with vue/vite?

Unfortunately I couldn't really find any specific information regarding CSP usage with vue/vite in their respective official docs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77627472/do-browsers-ignore-style-src-csp-directive-for-style-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly vue performs rendering, but I assume they use CSSOM, i.e. insert styles into DOM like this:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'red';
```

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src, this is not treated as CSP violation:

> However, styles properties that are set directly on the element's style property will not be blocked, allowing users to safely manipulate styles via JavaScript

See also:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336413

[Do browsers ignore style-src CSP directive for style attributes set from React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77627472/do-browsers-ignore-style-src-csp-directive-for-style-attributes-set-from-react)

Comment: I suppose that would make sense, though it seems strange at first glance an inline style would be converted like that. Part of the build output for the example is `()=>F("div", {style:{background:"red"}}` so it seems reasonable that vue would use that with CSSOM.