# Do browsers ignore style-src CSP directive for style attributes set from React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, content-security-policy

I'm setting the following directive for content security policy: `style-src 'self' 'nonce-{NONCE_GOES_HERE}` for my web app. I'd expect inline styles (added using `style` attribute) not to be applied. But in fact they are, despite the error messages about CSP violation are thrown for each inline style.
The same is observed when I use `style-src-attr` directive.
This occurs in recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari.
Is this behavior expected? If yes, is this specified anywhere (CSP spec says the opposite)?

UPD: This is reproducible using React. With plain HTML+CSS the directives work as intended. See examples: https://undeletable.name/CSP/
Minimal reproduce conditions:

- Any React app which contains component with `style` property
- `<head>` of the web page should contain `<meta>` tag with CSP which doesn't allow inline styles (`unsafe-inline`). For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' 'nonce-bm9uY2U='" />
```

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src-attr 'none'" />
```

Comment: Could it be that you have (accidentally, perhaps) it set to _reporting_ only? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only

Comment: @CBroe Not my case: the same directive works as expected for `<style>` elements.

Comment: How did you set the `style-src-attr` directive? You should set it to `'none'` if you want inline styles to not get applied... Indeed, that's what happens when I set up a quick [node/express StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6pabpj?file=index.js) and run it (`node index.js`)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've set the same value for `style-src-attr` as for `style-src`. According to your suggestion, I've set it to `'none'`, but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: Well, the StackBlitz shows it working (at least in Chrome & Firefox latest versions on Win 10) so there must be something else at work... Provide a [mre]?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I see the expected behavior by the link you provided. Not sure if that matters, but the only significant difference is that the page there is displayed inside iframe.

Comment: @HereticMonkey When I use plain HTML, directives work as expected. But for React (which is my original use case), they aren't applied for inline styles, and there's even no console error thrown. https://undeletable.name/CSP/

Comment: I would [edit] your question with the exact [mre] of the React code that produces the issue. You may be able to use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) to create a runnable code block here (saving people a trip to an external site that may change later).

Comment: @HereticMonkey This sounds like a good idea, but looks like it's not possible to define CSP for the snippet, so that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's possible because React uses CSSOM (i.e. setting style like `document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'red'`. In fact, this doesn't violate CSP directives which prohibit inline styles.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29089970/3887471

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336413

https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/11697

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src

> However, styles properties that are set directly on the element's style property will not be blocked, allowing users to safely manipulate styles via JavaScript